# store values from a list into an array after each iteration consists of specified column of files in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For a file in files:

This is my list which consists of values from 3 files after each iteration.

```
import pandas                                                                                   files = [r"C:\Users\Anjana\Documents\radar\HeightVsDopplr\EXP_DBS_CH4_24Apr2017_10_49_10_Beam2_W1_Az_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts",r"C:\Users\Anjana\Documents\radar\HeightVsDopplr\EXP_DBS_CH4_24Apr2017_10_49_10_Beam4_W1_Az_180.00_Oz_10.00.mmts", r"C:\Users\Anjana\Documents\radar\HeightVsDopplr\EXP_DBS_CH4_24Apr2017_10_49_10_Beam1_W1_Az_0.00_Oz_0.00.mmts"]                                                                      
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".mmts"):                                                                          
        csvfiles.append(str(file))
```

```
a = pd.read_csv(file)
x = list(a0[:][:]['Mean'])           
matrix = np.empty((a0.shape[0],3))
matrix.fill(np.nan)
```

#### I need the output somewhat like this

- matrix(row1,col1) should be value of first value from file 1
- matrix(row2,col1) should be value of first value from file 2
- matrix(row3,col1) should be value of first value from file 3 
  sample input:

> file 1

+--------+----------+
| Height |     Mean |
+--------+----------+
|   3.33 | -0.41005 |
+--------+----------+
|   3.51 |  0.15782 |
+--------+----------+
|   3.69 |  0.12896 |
+--------+----------+

> file 2

+--------+--------+
| Height |  Mean  |
+--------+--------+
|  3.33  | 1.8867 |
+--------+--------+
|  3.51  | 2.3108 |
+--------+--------+
|  3.69  | 2.5924 |
+--------+--------+

> output

```
array[-0.41005,0.15782 ,0.12896]
      [1.8867 ,2.3108 ,2.5924]
```

Comment: Why are you saying `for file in files` as if you want to iterate over the files? Just open them and read whatever you need to.

Comment: i need to know how the values from 3 files to be stored in array..by row wise (first row of each file to the first column of new array likewise 122 values )i to this new array of 122 col and 3 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks the context, so I'm assuming that

1. You've three files to read.

So I've 3 files, `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`.

> `a.txt`

```
1
2
3
```

> `b.txt`

```
paul
sleeba
harry
```

> `a.txt`

```
23
25
34
```

2. You need to get individual access these file contents so that you can enlist them in particular columns.

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as a, open("b.txt", "r") as b, open("c.txt", "r") as c:
    num = a.readlines()
    name = b.readlines()
    age = c.readlines()

print(num[0], name[0], age[0])
```

---

Output

```
1
paul
23
```

---

I see that you're using `numpy`, but I can't help about it since the plot of question is hardly helping to understand the context.

---

Update: I still don't understand your confusion with different files since question is vague, but follow the code for each column in a file.

> My CSV

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
out_list = [] 

for col in a.columns.values:  
    out_list.append(list(a[col]))

out_list = np.array(out_list)
print(out_list)
```

> Output

```
array([['All industries  ', 'All industries  ', 'All industries  ',
        'All industries  ', 'All industries  ', 'All industries  ',
        'All industries  ', 'All industries  ', 'All industries  ',
        'All industries  '],
       ['H01', 'H04', 'H05', 'H07', 'H08', 'H09', 'H10', 'H11', 'H12',
        'H12'],
       ['644159', '567080', '59317', '17762', '560665', '33474', '6890',
        '18730', '99874', '99874']], dtype='<U16')
```

---

UPDATE : From different files

```py
out_list = [] 

files = ["1.csv", "2.csv"]
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    out_list.append(list(df["Mean"]))

out_list = np.array(out_list)
out_list
```

> Output

```
array([[-0.41005,  0.15782,  0.12896],
       [ 1.8867 ,  2.3108 ,  2.5924 ]])
```

Comment: okay  mam,thanks   ..i need to know how it can store in an array with entire value... i have  included some more code

Comment: It is not a Ms or Mrs but Mr here. Thanks.

Comment: okay sir, my question was , how can I write the code to store values ....to each of this statements  using loop                                                                              `matrix[i,0]= # values of first file
matrix[i,1]= ?  # values of second file
matrix[i,2]= ?   # values of third file   with this statements itself

Comment: You can see how I did build a matrix from different columns in a single file. For your 3 file use case, read three files, then select the column values from each file, and append it to a list. Convert the final `list of a list` to a `numpy` array if you need to.

Comment: If it is not what you expect, please post a sample of your input files and the file you need as output. Your explanation seems bit complicated. Do try to use proper markdown tools to write a readable comment and question.

Comment: **sample input:**
'
**file 1**
_Height,Mean _ 
3.33,-0.41005
3.51,0.15782
3.69,0.12896

**file 2**
_Height,Mean_
3.33,1.8867
3.51,2.3108
3.69,2.5924

**output**
array[-0.41005,0.15782 ,0.12896]
      [1.8867 ,2.3108 ,2.5924]'

Comment: I've updated the code. It is quite similar to the logic of the previous update in the answer. All you had to do was to read files in a loop. Do keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service, rather it helps you to get ideas and perspectives for your problem from other fellow coders. Do develop a trait to push yourself using the clues rather than demanding for exact solutions.

Comment: Sir, I have tried in the same way as u said  before,since I haven't met with the desired output I ask for some more help..Pardon me since I am basic begginer to python, and trying my best to find the solution.Thankyou

Comment: @AnjanaJoseph Please mark it as the answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general. Try to provide a minimal complete verifiable example otherwise it is difficult to help you.

What is in the files? Is each line a number? Too few information.

In Python you can use multiple iteration variables.

```
#open the files first
f1 = open("file1", "r")
f2 = open("file2", "r")
f3 = open("file3", "r")

#Assuming the files have the same number of lines:
for linef1, linef2, linef3 in zip(file1,file2,file3):
    #Assuming each line is a number
    matrix[i,0]= int(linef1)
    matrix[i,1]= int(linef1)
    matrix[i,2]= int(linef1)
```

Comment: thankyou...can you suggest way to store this values by using list consist of specified column values...i am new to python please help